# smack 4.2.0 bug with ChatStateManager

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

Hi I'm developing android chat app, I want to know the user typing notification so i used

```
    editor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                ChatStateManager.getInstance(conn1).setCurrentState(ChatState.composing,chatObj);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

but it accepts only deprecated Chat object and not the newer version of ChatObject as per smack 4.2.0 and as per smack documentation ChatStateManger is not deprecated does anyone know how to fix this or has anyone implemented ChatState using version 4.2.0. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ChatStateManager in Smack 4.2 uses the deprecated Chat API. [Smack 4.3 will use the new API](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-761).

Comment: ho i see thank u for rising up the issue.. Can u please tell me what is the suggested way to get user chat status for now ?? shd we go with smack 4.1 ?? or if there is any alternatives with Smack 4.2 ?

Comment: Simply use Smack's 4.2 ChatStateManager for now.

Comment: yeah that's the issue now the second parameter to ChatStateManager is not of the chat2 type, so shd we use old chat object oly ??

Comment: have you find any solution for this problem @Moulesh?

Comment: @FazalHussain yup on sender side we can compose custom message and add the details you need to identify user specific info and in addition to that add the ChatStateExtension namespace for all your typing state msgs, On receiver side u can filter them using stanza extension filter for your process stanza method

Comment: Kindly provide me the link which helps me. I have setup extension like this https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fazalBykea/5049aabd2001d98458c4f8a5f3bc427e/raw/e9410ccb79ae5b398f28821bcf757abfe83e58bd/MessageExtension